# After fresh installation Window 7 not logging in

Tags: windows-7, drivers, windows-installation

I have Lenovo G580 laptop. I was updating drivers, after updating power driver window ask for reboot. When I restart windows It just prompt message for `repairing [recommended]`. I tried for repairing but hard luck. After that I tried for fresh installation of `windows7 Ultimate x64` (previous version of windows is same), it is taking a lot time (3 hours) for installation and still getting same message for repair.

Can someone help me to fix this problem. How can I format my `C` drive and get a fresh copy of Windows.

I am using USB for installation windows.

EDIT: I tried CHKDSK in command prompt and windows has checked the file system and found no problem. So I think HDD is not corrupted. Any suggestion.

EDIT 2: Hi I tried for `safe mode` and system boots fine and I can login to `safe mode`, but again when I tried for `normal boot` it hangs again. I tried to open `msconfig` but it is asking for `Administrator` privilege even though I don`t have admin account. Any pointers regarding Normal boot process. between I am following this [link](https://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/179159-troubleshoot-application-conflicts-performing-clean-startup.html).

It is showing two accounts in safe mode for only one user.

Comment: Sounds like a HDD problem.  Your installation of the drivers just happened to hammer the final nail in it's coffin.  It's time to replace the HDD.  "How can I format my C drive and get a fresh copy of Windows." - Boot to the installation disk, format the HDD, and install Windows.

Comment: @Ramhound... Actually installation itself not starting properly. Are you sure HDD got corrupted. Should I try for external HDD to give it a chance.

Comment: I can't be sure your HDD has failed, you didn't provide information proving it was/wasn't failing, the evidence you provide hints towards that fact.  If you want an answer that says one way or another without a shadow of a doubt provide more evidence

Comment: Boot up to the windows 7 install.  Before clicking anything try pressing either F8 or shift+F10.  If that gets you a command prompt, then try running `diskpart`.  Use `list disk` to find your disk you want to reformat.  Make it the "active" disk for diskpart with `select disk #` where # is the number of your disk.  use `clean` to format it **this will wipe everything on the drive***.  Reboot and retry the install of Windows.

Comment: Hi all please check updated question, and provide me any solution.

Comment: its possible that your USB is starting to fail. Bad medium or slow medium can cause exactly what your experiencing